# Max limit on number of elements in source of Autocomplete jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, search, autocomplete, frontend

I want to implement an autocomplete feature similar to google search. I have input list of 600 elements from which I want to search from and show suggestions. I was looking into jQuery UI autocomplete feature and have few questions:
1. Is there any limit on number of elements I can put in [source of autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)?
2. Is there any performance impact in terms of latency of using such larger dataset?
3. Is there any other better alternate?

Comment: You can use LIMIT to shorten the results by whatever query retrieves the data. We have search fields where the query limit is 100 to avoid literally 40,000 possible matched suggestions, but we also expect at least 3 character input before searching. The user has to type a few more characters to find better matches, which is still limited to 100.

Comment: I would not use jQuery UI Autocomplete as a search engine. There is no limit to the number of items you can use as a source, but consider that the performance and usability will be related to the Users web browser.

Comment: @Twisty What if I have already sorted list of 600 words provided by backend.

Comment: @learning_13 yes you can use an array or object containing 600 elements. Again, this will depend on the Users browser and ability. I don't suspect it will be much of an issue.